# Can't listen my new button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm load a button from script template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="addButton">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="element-empty">
         ELEMENT
    </button>
</script>
```

this button already loaded to the page by "load" button. now i want to listener this button ("element-empty") from javascript and use jquery

```
$( '#element-empty' ).click(function() {
   $(this).attr('class','myClass');
});
```

the problem, button "element-empty" can't detect from javascript. anyone know the solution???

Comment: Put the button into the body, not into the script ...

Comment: That looks like the answer.  Should it be added as an answer?

Comment: No, this question should be closed.

Comment: that is script for template, so i can load it to body or div without create new element from javascript by button "add". but the problem, after loaded to the page, i can't listener this button from javascript due to this button not loaded when page loaded (this button loaded if i push button "add")

Comment: Did you read any of this stuff yet?  https://api.jquery.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Event listeners are attached to DOM elements on page load. You either need to reattach this one or you can listen for click events on the `document` that target your button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#element-empty', function() {
   $(this).addClass('myClass');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, this problem is solved (y)

Comment: @AlexS I updated my code, you should be using jquery's `addClass` method instead of overwriting the class attribute (this may required you to use `removeClass()` as well)

Comment: many thanks :) very helpful